# Package Twitter4j does not exist after packaging Jar

Tags: java, maven, twitter4j

I am trying to create a Twitter app with Java, running the application from Idea works and the Tweet gets sent, however after running `mvn clean package` and `java -jat TwitterClient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, then clicking the send tweet button I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/conf/ConfigurationBuilder
        at company.fourleafclover.TwitterClient.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:59)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 36 more
```

my Main class and pom.xml:

```
package company.fourleafclover.TwitterClient;

import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Started!");


        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Twitter Client");

        JLabel lblKey = new JLabel("API Key:");
        JTextField tfKey = new JTextField(20);
        lblKey.setLabelFor(tfKey);

        JLabel lblSecret = new JLabel("API Secret:");
        JTextField tfSecret = new JTextField(20);
        lblSecret.setLabelFor(tfSecret);

        JLabel lblToken = new JLabel("Access Token:");
        JTextField tfToken = new JTextField(20);
        lblToken.setLabelFor(tfToken);

        JLabel lblASecret = new JLabel("Access Secret:");
        JTextField tfAsecret = new JTextField(20);
        lblASecret.setLabelFor(tfAsecret);

        JLabel lblmsg = new JLabel("Message:");
        JTextField tfmsg = new JTextField(20);
        lblmsg.setLabelFor(tfmsg);

        JButton btnGet = new JButton("Send tweet");

        btnGet.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String consumerKey = new String(tfKey.getText());
                        String consumerSecret = new String(tfSecret.getText());
                        String oAuthAccessToken = new String(tfToken.getText());
                        String oAuthAccessTokenSecret = new String(tfAsecret.getText());
                        String Msg = new String(tfmsg.getText());


                        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                                .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
                                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
                                .setOAuthAccessToken(oAuthAccessToken)
                                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(oAuthAccessTokenSecret);
                        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();


                        try {


                            Status status = twitter.updateStatus(Msg);
                            System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");


                        } catch (Exception te) {
                            te.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                "Tweet sent!");
                    }
                });

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("button");



        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());

        panel.add(lblKey);//API Key
        panel.add(tfKey);//Api Key
        panel.add(lblSecret);//Access Secret
        panel.add(tfSecret);panel.add(lblToken);//API Token
        panel.add(tfToken);//API Token
        panel.add(lblASecret);
        panel.add(tfAsecret);
        panel.add(lblmsg);
        panel.add(tfmsg);
        panel.add(btnLogin);
        panel.add(btnGet);

        jtextfielddemo.SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel,
                6, 2, //rows, cols
                6, 6, //initX, initY
                6, 6); //xPad, yPad

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(470, 200);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);









    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>company.fourleafclover</groupId>
    <artifactId>TwitterClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotenv-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>company.fourleafclover.TwitterClient.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have also tried downladoing and importing Twitter4j-core into the Module Settings, which had no effect. [Module Settings](https://arch.best/YdNDNaFc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your build tag.

This works fine for me. You than have to take the one with jar-with-dependencies

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Your.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>16</source>
                <target>16</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yup, that worked,  I assume then that twitter4j just wasnt getting packed into my Jar then. Thanks!